# How to design best REST endpoint for hierarchical data

Tags: rest

Consider I have below tables in my db

## Project

Project_id ( int) PK

Name( string)

Description (string)

## Project_employee

Project_employee_id (int) Pk

Emp_id (int) FK

Project_id (int) FK

project_join_date (date)

I want to the rest endpoint for following requirements

1. Get all the project_employees for given project
2. Get project_employee for given project_employee_id
3. Add project_employee
4. Update project_employee
5. Delete project_employee

My design of Rest endpoint for above requirement would be

www.myapp.com/app/v1.0/porjects/{id}/project-employees/{id}   GET PUT POST DELETE

"/projects/{id}" is useful only for the 1st requirement of getting all the employee of given project. For all other requirement  projects/{id} is not useful at all.

So I would like to know what would be the correct REST endpoint(s) for the above requirements.

Can I get the any REST API best practice document? Also need document/Book for designing REST API.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a separate `/employees` resource so that you can manage employees without having to specify a project ID, or even to have employees which are not currently assigned to a project.

I'd still keep `/projects/:id/employees` though, so that you can manage the relationships between projects and employees, as below:

- Get all the project_employees for given project

  `GET /projects/:id/employees`
- Get project_employee for given project_employee_id

  `GET /employees/:id`
- Add project_employee

  `POST /projects/:id/employees`
- Update project_employee

  `PUT /employees/:id`
- Delete project_employee

  `DELETE /employees/:id`